# SQL Server Default Column value from function

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I want to set default value to `Id` column in `Person` table with a function
that goes like this:

Function:

```
IF OBJECT_ID ( 'GetLastId','FN') IS NOT NULL   
    DROP function GetLastId;  
GO  

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetLastId]
    (@TableName nvarchar(max)) 
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @LastId int;
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

    SET @sql = 'SELECT @LastId = ISNULL(MAX(Id), 0) + 1 FROM ' + @TableName + ';'

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, N'@LastId int output', @LastId = @LastId output;

    RETURN @LastId
END
```

and then:

```
UPDATE Person 
SET Id = dbo.GetLastId('Person')
```

Running this code throws an error:

> Only functions and some extended stored procedures can be executed from within a function.

So how to fix this and make it work as a default value?

And please do not say "Use triggers..." as I intend to use it with Entity Framework Core as default value for primary keys.

Thanks

Comment: Using max value is not concurrent safe, you will get conflicts between sessions. If you have to, you can generate separate function for each table, so you will not have to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: Do you know about the SQL IDENTITY property? I'm trying to understand why you wouldn't use that feature, which seems identical in function to what you are trying to achieve.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a stored procedure, not a function:

```
create procedure [dbo].[GetLastId] (
    @TableName nvarchar(max),
    @LastId int output
) as
begin
   declare @sql nvarchar(max);

   set @sql = 'select @LastId = ISNULL(MAX(Id), 0) + 1 from ' + @TableName + ';'
   EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql,
                         N'@LastId int output',
                         @LastId=@LastId output;
end;
```

You should also use `quotename()` around the table name to prevent unexpected things from happening.

Then you would call this as:

```
declare @lastId int;

exec dbo.GetLastId('Person', @lastid output); 

update Person
    set Id = @lastId;
```

Comment: wow, that was fast respond , i`ll check it out and give you big thumps up

Comment: "Incorrect Syntax near 'as'. Expecting ID" , what is wrong ?

Comment: fixed it , you forgot to change 'create function' to 'create procedure' ;)

Comment: still could not get it to work...
can you please provide full solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create [`stored procedure`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_stored_procedures.asp) instead of `function`

```
create procedure [dbo].[GetLastId] (
    @TableName nvarchar(max),
    @ColumnName nvarchar(200),
    @LastId int output
) as
begin
   declare @sql nvarchar(max);

   set @sql = 'select @LastId = ISNULL(MAX('+ @ColumnName +'), 0) + 1 from ' + @TableName + ';'
   EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql,
                         N'@LastId int output',
                         @LastId=@LastId output;
end;
```

Then you can execute `sp` like below

```
declare @lastId int

exec dbo.GetLastId 'Person', 'Id' , @lastid output;
select @lastId

update Person
set Id = @lastId;
```

Comment: how to make it as default value for Id column

Comment: You've already done with `ISNULL(MAX(Id), 0)` ? You can also do it like `set Id = ISNULL(@lastId, 0);`

Comment: I've just updated my answer with `@ColumnName` param to help you adjust the suitable column.